# how to count re tweet number in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, twitter

I want to count how many retweets in MongoDB.I got twitter data by streaming API.

Here is my different query but none of them worked..Please help me

```
db.collection.find({"retweet_count":{$ne:0}}).count()
db.collection.find({retweeted:ture}).count()
db.collection.find({retweeted:false}).count()
```

Related data structure

```
{ 
   "retweeted" : false, 
    "in_reply_to_status_id" : null, 
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null, 
    "is_quote_status" : false, 
    "id_str" : "815351057677094912", 
    "created_at" : "Sun Jan 01 00:16:55 +0000 2017", 
    "id" : NumberLong("815351057677094912"), 
    "retweet_count" : 0, 
    "truncated" : false, 
    "contributors" : null 
}
```

Comment: can you share a sample document stored in DB?

Comment: Hi Sidgate,please see  related data structure                                             
    :{
        "retweeted" : false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id" : null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : null,
        "is_quote_status" : false,
        "id_str" : "815351057677094912",

        "created_at" : "Sun Jan 01 00:16:55 +0000 2017",
        "id" : NumberLong("815351057677094912"),
        "retweet_count" : 0,
        "truncated" : false,
        "contributors" : null
}

Comment: did you try `db.collection.find({retweeted:true}).count()`  ? whats the output? what is expected?

Comment: I did,the output is 0 . It looks like retweeted filed is always false.I actually tried "mongoexport", so I can look what that field said.It turns out it is all saying false. So I think we need to look at (retweet_count)field.